# Forward second keyboard input to window and split-screen terminal and KDE

Tags: linux, input, tty

I have two keyboards (one internal and one external) and I want to split-screen Linux video output so I'll have tty on one half and X11 on second half and I want redirect input from external keyboard to first half and from internal mouse and keyboard to X11 half.

Is this possible, and if it is - how to do it?